# Add custom comment option when recommending deletion

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have recently started frequenting the "Low Quality Post" review queue, and I am coming across quite a few cases that require custom comments (and sometimes custom action) on my part.

Today, these have primarily involved answers which state the question has been answered elsewhere. For these I have been taking the following actions:

**If the answer is several years old and the user looks inactive**

1. I open the question in a new tab.
2. flag the question as a duplicate myself with the link in the answer.
3. add a comment to the answer stating that is what I've done, and am recommending the comment for deletion.
4. I then go back to the review queue and recommend deletion choosing the "no comment needed" option.

**If the answer is new or the user is active**

5. I open the question in a new tab.
6. Add a comment to the answer stating they should flag the question or add a comment (similar to the the "This is a commentary on another post") answer.

In both cases, the ability to add a custom comment when recommending deletion would streamline this process, and I'm sure other situations warrant custom comments too.

Comment: I realise that the "this is commentary on another post" is sufficient for the second case provided, but I think being able to provide more specific feedback is useful.

Comment: There reasons for voting to close are finite and documented. Anyone willing to read and understand the documentation should be able to identify at least one reason for the vote you cast. The suggested feature would create an additional, unnecessary hurdle to deletion, potentially slowing the useful and necessary process of removing unsuitable content from the site.

Comment: I disagree: we already have the "custom comment" option for closing questions, and I feel that in some cases it may not be clear why my vote was cast, so a custom comment can alleviate the ambiguity.

Comment: Would you be willing to give examples of delete reasons not covered in the documentation, and perhaps clarify how others would benefit from knowing those reasons?

Comment: Well the one in the question is useful: perhaps the poster doesn't know about the flag option? I will have to come back and add to the post as I come across more situations I feel warrant a custom comment.

Comment: Another option I just found missing: Recommend deletion because it is blatant spam